# How to open .vnt file in a Windows Computer

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile-phone

.vnt is the file format used for memos/notes in various bada/android/windows phones. Having created the file in Mobile and transfered to computer via Bluetooth, I am not able to open it. It opens in .txt but we cannot see the actual content at all.

The particular file I want to view has been created as a memo by a Samsung Champ Duos 2 Mobile. It is not a smartphone, but this particular format is very common and is used in various bada/windows/android phones.

Comment: You could run an android emulator?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick What's that?

Comment: "[The Android SDK includes a mobile device emulator — a virtual mobile device that runs on your computer. The emulator lets you develop and test Android applications without using a physical device.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)"

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What device created the file? What software on that device created the file? Did you just create a blank contact with no data? Does the file claim to have any data in it, i.e. is the filesize >0 bytes? How are you trying to view them?  Does *anything* at all show up or is it just garbage?  Have you tried transferring the files by any other means such as USB or memory card?

Comment: @Mokubai I have edited my question to accomdate for the data you asked/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eug48 wrote a [vnote to text convertor](https://bitbucket.org/eug48/vnote2txt/downloads) in Python.

The text is there, it is just encoded in ["quoted printable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) or other form.

Comment: I am not able to find a link to download it, I downloaded a file named "vnote2txt.py", but its file type is unrecognized.

Comment: @RishabhPoddar: You need a [Python interpreter](http://www.python.org/getit/windows/).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python script [Samsung-Sony-notes-.vnt-clean-text](https://github.com/yerb/Samsung-Sony-notes-.vnt-clean-text)
 that merges multiple .vnt files into one clean text file.

This is the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ufowNu/1/) used to extract data.